# How to add a new element to my JSON response using node js

Tags: node.js, json, jsonresponse

Below is my JSON response

```
[
  { lat: '53.46424526', lng: '-8.00847728' },
  { lat: '53.13914933', lng: '-8.93006114' },
  { lat: '53.34009165', lng: '-8.24123887' },
  { lat: '53.27250955', lng: '-8.62775527' },
  { lat: '52.85459678', lng: '-8.96581734' },
  { lat: '52.93174741', lng: '-8.43590219' },
  { lat: '52.82965853', lng: '-8.98572402' },
  { lat: '52.65745518', lng: '-7.23952916' },
  { lat: '52.65497914', lng: '-7.24017802' } 
]
```

and I want to add a new field to this response.
The expected JSON response is below

```
{
  "locations":[
  { lat: '53.46424526', lng: '-8.00847728' },
  { lat: '53.13914933', lng: '-8.93006114' },
  { lat: '53.34009165', lng: '-8.24123887' },
  { lat: '53.27250955', lng: '-8.62775527' },
  { lat: '52.85459678', lng: '-8.96581734' },
  { lat: '52.93174741', lng: '-8.43590219' },
  { lat: '52.82965853', lng: '-8.98572402' },
  { lat: '52.65745518', lng: '-7.23952916' },
  { lat: '52.65497914', lng: '-7.24017802' } 
]
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: sure, `response = {locations:response}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
let data = [
  { lat: '53.46424526', lng: '-8.00847728' },
  { lat: '53.13914933', lng: '-8.93006114' },
  { lat: '53.34009165', lng: '-8.24123887' },
  { lat: '53.27250955', lng: '-8.62775527' },
  { lat: '52.85459678', lng: '-8.96581734' },
  { lat: '52.93174741', lng: '-8.43590219' },
  { lat: '52.82965853', lng: '-8.98572402' },
  { lat: '52.65745518', lng: '-7.23952916' },
  { lat: '52.65497914', lng: '-7.24017802' } 
]

data = {locations:data}
```